# How to provide CDK-generated resource names to your application code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

Let's say you have a CDK app that deploys an S3 bucket with an auto-generated name. In the same repository you have an application that needs to know this bucket name. What is the best practice for providing this name to the application?

Some approaches I am considering:

1. Hardcode the output of `cdk synth`. This involves piecing together the Physical ID of the resource from the Logical ID, which is a hack and furthermore it doesn't work for resources that were imported into the stack whose physical ID is only to be found on AWS Console.
2. Define the necessary IDs as stack outputs and hardcode their values as provided by `cdk deploy`. This actually seems fine for my use case, but I don't like having to do a dangerous operation just to extract some IDs. (EDIT: I just realized `aws cloudformation describe-stacks` is a better alternative)
3. Define SSM Parameters as part of the CDK stack and inject the resource IDs into those parameters. I am not a fan of relying on a remote service for configuration, so I would probably have to fetch these values at deploy-time when releasing my application code.

Amazon documentation pushes against hardcoding so that you could hypothetically spin up instances of your application on another AWS account or region, but for my small business this is really overkill. I have nothing against hardcoding non-secret configuration.

EDIT: In the meantime I am implementing option 2 above, dumping the following JSON into my repo to be imported by my code:

```
> aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name CommonStack | jq '.Stacks[0].Outputs | map({ (.OutputKey): .OutputValue }) | add'
{ MyBucketName: "my-bucket-name" }
```

Comment: You said "In the same repository", just want to understand where exactly you want to refer the S3 bucket name? within the same CDK stack, or outside the CDK stack i.e. inside environment.ts of  Angular app

Comment: Outside the stack! That’s the key. Whether it’s the same git repository is actually not essential to my question.

Comment: If it is a server application, you can save those generated values in Build Variables, and from there you can copy them to environment variable of the server where you application will be running. If it is a frontend app, then you can generate browser bundles by referencing those variables, again, they should be stored somewhere, so that we can retrieve them during the pipeline run. I am not saying this is the best practice, but this is what I did personally for one of my application.

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion @AnkushJain! What exactly are "Build Variables" though? Is that just stack Outputs? I am now implementing option 2 as a temporary solution, see my edit.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention. I used CDK in Azure DevOps. Build variables are used in Azure DevOps.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud-side techniques like [Environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda.Function.html#environment) or [SSM Parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ssm-readme.html) are natural solutions to share resource identifiers with cloud-side application code.

---

Nevertheless, you can save `CfnOutput` values to disk at deploy-time with the `--outputs-file` flag.  This makes it easy to consume resource identifiers locally in CLI commands, or for [local testing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/sam.html).

Set resource values with a [CfnOutput](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib-readme.html#stack-outputs) construct:

```js
new cdk.CfnOutput(this, "BucketName", { value: bucket.bucketName });
```

Use a flag to persist the results to disk:

```
cdk deploy --outputs-file cdk.outputs.json
```

`cdk.outputs.json`:

```json
{
  "MyStack6CDBDE16": {
    "BucketName": "mystack6cdbde16-mybucketf68f3ff0-1hc6tiecjann2"
  }
}
```

Comment: This is basically my option 2 above. I decided to implement this option in my project, but using `aws cloudformation describe-stacks` to produce the outputs. Your answer should help some people, but I think I'll leave the question open for now because I still feel like there is another approach I am missing.